# How to insert data in listbox control in ASP from database row by row

Tags: asp.net, listbox

i had 7 columns in my tabel and i want to display all the data in list box one after another not in a single line with where clause condition "where name = @nameTextBox" where nameTextBox is a TextBox on the same page

Example

Joe Inc = this is the value of Text Box

Joe 
12 gold Street
Pincode 10010
PHone-+121212

this is the type of format to be retrieve from databse

Answer (score 0):

```
yourListBox.Items.Add ( "value from db" );
```

[ListBox.Items Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx)

your db should return name and his address and from the front end you can filter the resulting dataset by using a dataview and its rowfilter property. Then combine these cvalues and show using Items.Add method.

[DataView.RowFilter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)